# parseJSON decoding array

Tags: jquery, parsing, json

I first did a MySQL query and stored the rows in exArray as follows:

```
$exArray = array();
index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
     $exArray[$index] = $row; //Total of three rows
     $index++;
}
```

Then, I used

```
json_encode($exArray);
```

[{"first":"001","second":"002"},{"first":"003","second":"004"}]

Note: Data in my query.php contains more elements. I shortened it here for the sake of brevity. In reality, it is an array of three rows and eight columns. Here, I'm showing two rows and two columns.

Here's what I've tried.

First, I tried using the code below and alert the "001" without success. The alert simply doesn't pop up on my screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('query.php', function(data) {        
        if(data)
        {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj[0].first);
        }   
        });
    });
```

I've tried this method as well. I would like to push this.first into an array. I tried to append the "001" to a paragraph of class='test'. But, I did not succeed either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('query.php', function(data) {        
        if(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(){
            $(this.first).appendTo(".test")
            }  
        });
    });
```

Your help is more than welcome. Thank you.

Comment: what is `data` in your `$.each()` function? Could you post your exact code, expected result, and actual result?

Comment: Are you sure `data` is a json string and not just an array.

Comment: Please show actual issue - your sample value for `data` works perfectly fine (alert show 001 as expected). Most likely `data` contains something different.

Comment: Edited the question and provided more information. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In the php file, I first called,

```
 json_encode($exArray);
```

Then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('vconj.php', function(data) {        
        if(data)
        {
        alert(data[0].first);
        }   
        });
    });
```

Alerts 001 successfully. There was no need to use jQuery.parseJSON(data).

Thanks.